# Invalid key hash

Tags: android, facebook

Hi I'm very new to facebook login. I tried to generate a hash key for facebook android app. The first time it didn't asked for a password and gave me the hash key but now when I again tried to generate the hash key its asking for pass. When I enter "android" as pass, it gives me just DrNQ.

**command used:**

```
 keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Sam\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\Openssl\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\Openssl\bin\openssl" base64
```

[image: here is the screenshot of CMD]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using to much complex trick to get hash key of your application it's having lots of chance to get error.But I have one simple idea to generate your application hash key.
for generating hash key you must need to specify your package name and you are just putting following code while app is lunch and you are getting yout app hash key in Log.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.example.chirag.maptesting",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Hash Key :"+Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
}
```

**Note :**
in Above code com.example.chirag.maptesting is my application package name but you must need to paste your package name here.

I hope your are clear with my idea.

**Best Luck**

Comment: Can I use this code to get other package's hask key from different app?

Comment: Yes,Definitely you just replace package name and get this particular package name hash key.but make sure you must need to develop application in android not in any other platform.

Answer (score 0):

Using below code snippet, you can get the hash code.

```
public static String printKeyHash(Activity context) {
    PackageInfo packageInfo;
    String key = null;
    try {
        //getting application package name, as defined in manifest
        String packageName = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

        //Retriving package info
        packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName,
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

        Log.e("Package Name=", context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

        for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            key = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));

            // String key = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
            Log.e("Key Hash=", key);
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
        Log.e("Name not found", e1.toString());
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e("No such an algorithm", e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
    }

    return key;
}
```